# Replacing multiple delimited blocks in sed

Tags: sed

I have a body of text which contains groups delimited with <>,## or ||.
The blocks never overlap, but may cross multiple lines, like so:

```
#A fully emphasized line#
A line with #emphasis inside#.
#Several lines of
text
With emphasis#
no emphasis
Line #with# multiple #emphasis#.
Line <with some > |text of| #each type#.
```

I'm attempting to replace each pair of delimiters with [ and ] **and** put the final delimiter after the ]; for example the last line **should** be:

```
Line [with some ]> [text of]| [each type]#.
```

I have formed a sed script which will do the first part:

```
sed -e ':left s/[#|<]/[/; t right; n; b left :right s/[#|>]/]/; t left;n; b right'
```

But when I try to use & (or (..) + \1) to put the character back in like this:

```
sed -e ':left s/[#|<]/[/; t right; n; b left :right s/[#|>]/]&/; t left;n; b right'
```

I get the following:

```
[A fully emphasized line][
A line with ][emphasis inside][.
][Several lines of
text
With emphasis][
no emphasis
Line ][with][ multiple ][emphasis][.
Line [with some ]]]]]]> [text of[ [each type[.
```

I'm not sure what has gone wrong here though - it appears to be screwing with the pattern block in some way. I could replace it with three calls (hardcoded one per match type), but that seems excessive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following command. It reads the whole file in memory and do global substitutions for each pair of delimiters:

```
sed -e '
    :a
    $! { N; ba };
    s/#\([^#]*\)#/[\1]#/g; 
    s/<\([^>]*\)>/[\1]>/g; 
    s/|\([^|]*\)|/[\1]|/g
' infile
```

It yields:

```
[A fully emphasized line]#
A line with [emphasis inside]#.
[Several lines of
text
With emphasis]#
no emphasis
Line [with]# multiple [emphasis]#.
Line [with some ]> [text of]| [each type]#.
```

Comment: Cool. The merged version works with this as well, so the three searches can be replaced with: `s/[#|<]\([^#|>]*\)\([#|>]\)/[\1]\2/g;`

Comment: user2596375 - The three sed expressions are superior because your pattern replaces any pair of delimiters, not necessarily matching ones. `#text>`, for example, will be replaced with `[text]>` even though it's not `#text#`.